# Tomcat 9 and Eclipse Neon - Unknown version of Tomcat was specified

Tags: server, apache2, java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm having problems when trying to add Tomcat as a runtime environment in Eclipse Neon.
I have tried multiple solutions I found here on the forums, none of them worked. I have the tomcat folder in /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21, and when I put that path in Eclipse, it says "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified.".
I really need this to work... 
Ubuntu: 16.04
Eclipse: Neon
Tomcat: 9.0.0.M21

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by having the tomcat files in the Downloads directory instead of /usr/local.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the logged in user does not have the read permission of tomcat installation directory. To give required permission, run below command,

```
sudo chown -R logged_in_user installation_directory
```